# Check whether array element is present in hash and delete it : Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash and an array. I want to check whether an array element is in the hash as a key, and if not, delete the key from the hash.

```
RegionScoreHash={"A"=>1, "B"=>0, "C"=>0, "D"=>1, "E"=>0, "F"=>0, "G"=>0}
RegionsArray=["B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

**Result Required:** Hash with elements present in array (`A` and `G` regions removed)

```
ResultHash={"B"=>0, "C"=>0, "D"=>1, "E"=>0, "F"=>0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array`'s `delete_if` method to modify the hash in place.

```
RegionScoreHash.delete_if { |k| !RegionsArray.include?(k) }
```

or use something like `select` if you want a new result.

```
result = RegionScoreHash.select { |k| RegionsArray.include?(k) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting is inefficient.

```
ResultHash = RegionsArray.inject({}){|h, k| h[k] = RegionScoreHash[k]; h}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RegionScoreHash={"A"=>1, "B"=>0, "C"=>0, "D"=>1, "E"=>0, "F"=>0, "G"=>0} 
 RegionsArray=["B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
 RegionScoreHash.delete_if {|a| !RegionsArray.include?(a)}
```

As advice the ruby way should be region_score_hash instead RegionScoreHash.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged `ruby-on-rails`, let's assume you have ActiveSupport's extensions to Enumerable, which allows use of [`exclude?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#exclude-questionmark)

Combine it with Hash's [`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) method

```
RegionScoreHash.delete_if { |k, _v| RegionsArray.exclude?(k) }
```

and you should get back a hash with only keys that are present in `RegionsArray`.